# How can I run some action when my plugin was deployed to Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I want to run some code as soon as my *plugin* (*portlet*, *hook* or *theme*) is available in Liferay.

I can't find anything like a *startup listener* in `liferay-plugin-package.xml`, `liferay-portlet.xml`, `liferay-hook.xml` or `liferay-look-and-feel.xml`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is another way. You could utilize the StartupAction. It is merely an Event, which get's triggered on every startup of a plugin. This method will only get triggered once on a server start or deploy. Recognize, that the doRun method get's a String array of companyIds as an argument. A companyId is representing a portal instance (the Liferay internal one. Not another application server.)

For instance, I have a portlet where I rely on some custom fields to exist. So I have this neat little class:

```
package de.osc.kaleositeaddon.startup;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.SimpleAction;

public class StartupAction extends SimpleAction {

    @Override
    public void run(String[] companyIds) throws ActionException {
        setupExpandoAction.run(companyIds);
        importMessagesAction.run(companyIds);
    }

    private SetupExpandoAction setupExpandoAction = new SetupExpandoAction();
    private ImportMessagesAction importMessagesAction = new ImportMessagesAction();
}
```

And the SetupExpandoAction is:

```
package de.osc.kaleositeaddon.startup;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.SimpleAction;
import com.liferay.portal.model.Group;
import com.liferay.portal.model.ResourceConstants;
import com.liferay.portal.model.Role;
import com.liferay.portal.model.RoleConstants;
import com.liferay.portal.security.permission.ActionKeys;
import com.liferay.portal.service.ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portlet.expando.DuplicateColumnNameException;
import com.liferay.portlet.expando.DuplicateTableNameException;
import com.liferay.portlet.expando.model.ExpandoColumn;
import com.liferay.portlet.expando.model.ExpandoColumnConstants;
import com.liferay.portlet.expando.model.ExpandoTable;
import com.liferay.portlet.expando.model.ExpandoTableConstants;
import com.liferay.portlet.expando.service.ExpandoColumnLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portlet.expando.service.ExpandoTableLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle;

import de.osc.kaleositeaddon.service.constants.ExpandoConstants;

public class SetupExpandoAction extends SimpleAction {

    @Override
    public void run(String[] companyIds) throws ActionException {
        for (int i = 0; i < companyIds.length; i++) {
            long companyId = Long.parseLong(companyIds[i]);
            try {
                setupExpandoGroup(companyId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void setupExpandoGroup(long companyId) throws Exception {
        ExpandoTable table = null;
        try {
            table = ExpandoTableLocalServiceUtil.addTable(companyId, Group.class.getName(), ExpandoTableConstants.DEFAULT_TABLE_NAME);
        } catch (DuplicateTableNameException dtne) {
            table = ExpandoTableLocalServiceUtil.getTable(companyId, Group.class.getName(), ExpandoTableConstants.DEFAULT_TABLE_NAME);
        }
        /*
         * Setup StartDate
         */
        try {
            ExpandoColumn column = ExpandoColumnLocalServiceUtil.addColumn(table.getTableId(),
                    ExpandoConstants.EXPANDO_COLUMN_NAME_START_DATE, ExpandoColumnConstants.DATE);
            column.setDefaultData("");
            Role user = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, RoleConstants.GUEST);
            ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.setResourcePermissions(companyId, ExpandoColumn.class.getName(), ResourceConstants.SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL,
                    String.valueOf(column.getColumnId()), user.getRoleId(), new String[] { ActionKeys.VIEW});
        }
        catch (DuplicateColumnNameException dcne) {
        }
        /*
         * Setup EndDate
         */
        try {
            ExpandoColumn column = ExpandoColumnLocalServiceUtil.addColumn(table.getTableId(),
                    ExpandoConstants.EXPANDO_COLUMN_NAME_END_DATE, ExpandoColumnConstants.DATE);
            column.setDefaultData("");
            Role user = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, RoleConstants.GUEST);
            ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.setResourcePermissions(companyId, ExpandoColumn.class.getName(), ResourceConstants.SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL,
                    String.valueOf(column.getColumnId()), user.getRoleId(), new String[] { ActionKeys.VIEW});
        }
        catch (DuplicateColumnNameException dcne) {
        }


        try {
            ExpandoColumn column = ExpandoColumnLocalServiceUtil.addColumn(table.getTableId(),
                    ExpandoConstants.EXPANDO_COLUMN_NAME_CREATE_DATE, ExpandoColumnConstants.DATE);
            column.setDefaultData("");
            Role user = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyId, RoleConstants.GUEST);
            ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.setResourcePermissions(companyId, ExpandoColumn.class.getName(), ResourceConstants.SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL,
                    String.valueOf(column.getColumnId()), user.getRoleId(), new String[] { ActionKeys.VIEW});
        }
        catch (DuplicateColumnNameException dcne) {
        }

    }

}
```

In your liferay-hook.xml file, you do the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 6.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_6_0_0.dtd">

<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>        
</hook>
```

And in portal.properties you add this line:

```
application.startup.events=de.osc.kaleositeaddon.startup.StartupAction
```

remember to substitute the class names ;)

Comment: Good answer, a little bit long - I would remove SetupExpandoAction. And its important to notice that it is triggered on every startup of a _plugin_ for every _portal instance_ (company) -

Comment: I added a reference to your answer in my answer. But your edit is not correct: if you check `HookHotDeployListener.initEvent` you will see that the action is (unfortunately) called once for every company with only the ID of that instance.

Comment: How is that unfortunate? If you want to ignore the instance, just keep a flag that you've already executed your initialization. Otherwise assume that it's a hint that you most likely forgot about initializing for instances (which should be totally separated from each other)

Comment: Ok, don't say _unfortunately_, say _unexpectedly_. Because from the interface it seams that I get _all_ company ids at once, not one per call. The documentation in portal.properties is misleading in another direction: _Application startup event that runs once for every **web site** instance of the portal that initializes_. I still think that for schedulers and overriding implementaions my answer fits better, as I have the possibility to deinstall everything when my plugin is undeployed (`application.shutdown.events` is not invoked by the HookHotDeployListener - maybe something for a CR...)

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a portlet in your plugin, you can run the code in `Portlet.init(PortletConfig)`.

But this is not always possible, because

- you've got no portlet
- you've got no own portlet implementation (e.g. because you use JSF)
- the code belongs to no portlet and you don't want to add it randomly to one of them

In that case you have two other options:

Create a startup action which is called for every portal instance (see the [answer of *gevatterjan*](/a/31054912/4371659)). This is the best solution if you need to run code for every portal instance.

Or you use a combination of `ServletContextListener` and `PortalLifecycle` which is started once when the plugin is available. This is the best solution if you want to run only once, e.g. to create a scheduler or to replace Liferay functions that are not covered by `liferay-hook.xml` resp. `portal.properties`.

```
@WebListener
public class MyStartupListener implements ServletContextListener, PortalLifecycle {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // Wait until the portal is ready
        PortalLifecycleUtil.register(this, PortalLifecycle.METHOD_INIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void portalInit() {
        // Here comes our initialization code
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Here comes our uninitialization code, if any
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void portalDestroy() {
        // Ignore
    }

}
```

You can call any Liferay functions, but be careful:

Your thread is not connected to any request - there is no current *portal instance* (`Company`), *site* (`Group`), *page* (`Layout`) or *user*. You can find all of these using the appropriate `*ServiceLocalUtil` functions. And for some actions you need to set these value for the thread in `CompanyThreadLocal`, `PricipalThreadLocal` and `PermissionThreadLocal`.