# Liferay Scheduler not working after server restart

Tags: java, liferay, scheduling

I am scheduling a job using the code below.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class MyController {

    @RenderMapping
    public String defaultView() {
        try {
            String cronText = "0 30 12 1/1 * ? *";
            String description = "Message Scheduler Description";
            String destinationName = DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH;
            int exceptionsMaxSize = 0;
            String portletId = "portletId";

            Message message = new Message();
            message.put(SchedulerEngine.MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME,SchedulerListener.class.getName());
            message.put(SchedulerEngine.PORTLET_ID, portletId);

            Trigger trigger = new CronTrigger(SchedulerListener.class.getName(), SchedulerListener.class.getName(), cronText);
            SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule(trigger,StorageType.PERSISTED, description, destinationName, message, exceptionsMaxSize);
        }catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "view";
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that the scheduler is valid only till the server session. Once this method is executed, I want to trigger the schedulerjob at the mentioned time even after a server restart. Is there a way to implement this in liferay?

Comment: As you are using StorageType.PERSISTED, I would guess, the job is persisted in your database. Can you check, if your `QUARTZ_...` tables exist and contain the job?

Comment: @TobiasLiefke yeah.. after restarting the server, the quartz table still contain the job. But still the job is not triggered

Comment: This answer on Liferay forums suggests to create a custom destination. Can you try?

https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11799978#_19_message_35509195

Comment: @TomasPinos in this context, I do not know where I could find the `init() method` inorder to add a custom destination to MessageBusUtil

Comment: They mean `com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet#init`. That's Liferay MVC framework. In your case, it can be any "init" method. Like a method annotated with `javax.annotation.PostConstruct` or even the controller's render method.

Comment: @TomasPinos I added the following code `Destination dest = new ParallelDestination("Sample Dest");
   MessageBusUtil.addDestination(dest);
   String destinationName = dest.getName();` instead of the SCHEDULER_DISPATCH line. It still did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the implementation of Liferay scheduling. Quartz is correctly storing and restoring your trigger and the job. But Liferay isn't using your `MessageListener` as a job. Instead it will wrap your `MessageListener` in a `MessageSenderJob` and it will register your `MessageListener`.

The `MessageSenderJob` will still be triggered after restart, and it will send your message to the message bus. But if you didn't registered your `MessageListener` until that point, their will be no receiver of that message.

*Solution:* You will have to register your `MessageListener` on every startup. Either by calling scheduling `SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule` again, or by calling `MessageBusUtil.registerMessageListener`. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046786/how-can-i-run-some-action-when-my-plugin-was-deployed-to-liferay/31046798#31046798) for some options to register startup actions.

Here an example in case you want to create the trigger dynamically (due to some action in the UI):

```
@WebListener
public class SchedulerListener implements ServletContextListener, PortalLifecycle, MessageListener {

    private SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper listenerWrapper;

    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // Wait until the portal is ready
        PortalLifecycleUtil.register(this, PortalLifecycle.METHOD_INIT);
    }

    public void portalInit() {
        // Register our listener
        listenerWrapper = new SchedulerEventMessageListenerWrapper();

        listenerWrapper.setGroupName(getClass().getName());
        listenerWrapper.setJobName(getClass().getName());
        listenerWrapper.setMessageListener(this);

        listenerWrapper.afterPropertiesSet();

        MessageBusUtil.registerMessageListener(DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, listenerWrapper);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Unregister
        if (listenerWrapper != null) {
            MessageBusUtil.unregisterMessageListener(DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, listenerWrapper);
        }
    }

    public void portalDestroy() {
        // Ignore
    }

    public void receive(final Message message) {
        // ... your job code here ...
    }

}
```

If you want to have a fixed trigger instead, you can drop the `listenerWrapper` and put your `SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule(...)` code from your question into `portalInit()`.

If you want to know, what's the point of `StorageType.PERSISTED`: It's for executing triggers that would have been fired while the server was down or that had just started as the server was going down.

Comment: I should add this Listener class in a portlet or hook? After adding this, if I deploy the plugin, will it get execute this class code automatically?

Comment: Portlet and Hook is working. The important thing is what you put in `message.put(SchedulerEngine.PORTLET_ID, "...")`. This must either be a full qualified portlet id (including `..._WAR_...`) or the servlet context name of your plugin (see `QuartzSchedulerEngine.registerMessageListeners`). For a hook the later applies. I don't understand your second question - you will need to use one of the options I've linked in my answer to execute something automatically. Do you want to turn on/off the scheduler from the UI dynamically or do you want a fixed trigger and scheduled action?

Comment: Well.. this worked :-) What does `PortalLifecycleUtil.register(this, PortalLifecycle.METHOD_INIT);` do? Is it necessary here?

Comment: It ensures, that your listener is not called until Liferay is up and running. Otherwise it could happen that some of the things you need for registration are still missing. I don't know if `MessageBusUtil.registerMessageListener` really needs a running Liferay, but `SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule` will need one for sure.