# Liferay execute some code automatically after server start

Tags: java, liferay

I have a Spring portlet with a controller having a structure as follows.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class MyController {

    @RenderMapping
    public String defaultView() {
        // some scheduling code
        return "view";
    }
}
```

This is a variation of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087551/liferay-scheduler-not-working-after-server-restart) for which I didn't get any answers.

We have this server restart at times. And we would like to avoid the intervention of an external person to manually do the scheduling again. As it is a portlet currently, it is necessary to render the view so that this code is executed. Is there a way to execute this scheduling code automatically right after the liferay server is started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Application startup event* is triggered when Liferay starts.

The event is handled by a custom action. Sample:

```
public class MyAction extends SimpleAction {
    @Override
    public void run(String[] companyIds) throws ActionException {
        // run, run
    }
}
```

The action is usually contained in a hook plugin. A hook plugin can be deployed as a separate application (ie. separate .war file), but it can also be part of your portlet application.

To implement the hook, you need to:

1) Register the action in a custom property file - let's say `portal-hooked.properties` (for Maven projects, the file will be located in `src/main/resources`):

```
#
# Application startup event that runs once for every web site instance of
# the portal that initializes.
#
application.startup.events=com.test.MyAction
```

2) Create the hook descriptor - `liferay-hook.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder (can be placed side-by-side with portlet descriptors, ie. `portlet.xml` and `liferay-portlet.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_6_1_0.dtd">

<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal-hooked.properties</portal-properties>
</hook>
```

Comment: Where should I create this MyAction class? Can I create the class in the same portlet?

Comment: Check my updated answer.